# MFC Syntax set Node as new Node

Tags: c++, syntax, mfc

Ive got a little question to my Syntax.
I made this Struct

```
struct Node
{
    CString name;
    CString vorname;
    CString geburtsdatum;
    CString adresse;
    CString plz;
    CString ort;
    CString email;
    CString geschlecht;
    CString land;
    CString firma;
    CString telefon;
    CString fax;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
};
Node *Actual;
const Node *Start;
```

So, this is in my .h File. Now I want into my .cpp File that `Start` is a `new Node`
It should be something this way `Start = new Node;`

Can you tell me the Syntax to do that?

Thanks

Comment: General tip: Don't *define* variables inside header files.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried doing that e.g. as the first thing in the `main` function?

Comment: Also, this is not PHP. C++ offers types beyond strings and structures of strings.

Comment: Also, to continue IInspectables questioning, both [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/942860sh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) provides containers, so you don't have to provide your own specialized list.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable is const, you could not modify it's content. I guess you'd like to have an ability to modify them but still keep pointer (Start) as const. The next code will do it.

```
// .h file
...
extern Node* const Start;

// .cpp file
Node* const Start = new Node();
int main()
{
    Start->name = "user2675121";
    delete Start;
    return 0;
}
```

Keyword 'extern' used with 'Start' (int .h file) tells compiler that this variable will be initialized somewhere else. And const should be placed after '*' to make a pointer (not its data) const.
But using a global variables is always a bad decision.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to do the following in your cpp file.
    start = new Node();

in that case why 'const node* start'. 
Making const, will not allow new data to be written on that variable.

My suggestion is removed 'const'

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Node
{
    int info;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;
};
int main()
{
    const Node* start ;
    int d = 4;
    start = new Node();
    start->info = d;
    printf("%d\t", start->info);

    return 0;
}
```

In this, at start->info says "Node::info readonly"..i.e you can't assign structure data on `start`. So kindly remove const and do necessary operations